# ReactJs get id instead of value from Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI Auto complete to get list of countries, and I need to get the selected country id to send back to database.

```
<Autocomplete
   options={this.state.countries.map(option => option.name_en + ` (${option.name_native})`)}
   id="discountType"
   value={this.state.makeCountry}
   onChange={(e, value) => this.logCountry(e, value)}
   renderInput={(params) =>
   <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      label="Select make country"
   />}
/>
```

I need to send option.id to logCountry function alongside the value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When creating your `options`, you can turn them into objects in a format such as:

```
const options = this.state.countries.map(option => ({ id: option.id, label: option.name_en + ` (${option.name_native})`}));
```

An then you can access the selected option id using `onChange={(e, value) => this.logCountry(e, value.id)}`.

I've forked the [MUI Autocomplete's docs](https://mui.com/pt/components/autocomplete/#combo-box) stackblitz example to implement such behavior, you can check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aejobs?file=demo.js).

Comment: It worked. I just had to use getOptionLabel instead of value. Thank you so much.