# How would I be able to pass the product ID according to what product was selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a dynamic form where users can add multiple products. I wonder how I could save the selected products'  id.

In the  `console.log(fields, "fields");`, this is where I can see the saved product. So how can I save the selected product id as well?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-from-reddit-with-data-ouy64e?file=/src/fieldArray.js:322-4143

```
const products = [
  {
    prodName: "Tumbler",
    price: 1.5,
    size: "500",
    colorMap: { Black: 20, Pink: 10, Green: 5 },
    id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV"
  },
  {
    prodName: "Shirt",
    price: 2.0,
    size: "L",
    colorMap: { Blue: 10, Black: 10 },
    id: "uTHIR6OQFRuqP9Drft0e"
  },
  {
    size: "200",
    price: 2.0,
    colorMap: { Green: 50, Red: 19, Black: 20 },
    prodName: "Notebook",
    id: "y9ECyZBKp2OBekmWym4M"
  }
];

const options = products.map(
  (object) =>
    object.prodName +
    " - " +
    object.size +
    `${object.cat === "CM" || object.cat === "ML" ? "- " + object.cat : ""}` +
    " "
);

console.log(options, "options");

const FieldArray = ({ control, register, setValue, getValues }) => {
  const { fields, append, remove, prepends } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "order"
  });

  console.log(fields, "fields");

  renderCount++;

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(item);
          return (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <Controller
                control={control}
                name={`order.${index}.product`}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value = "", ...rest } }) => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    {...rest}
                    onInputChange={(e, newValue) => {
                      onChange(newValue);
                      console.log(newValue, "new value");
                    }}
                    inputValue={value}
                    options={products}
                    // isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                    //   option?.value === value?.value
                    // }
                    getOptionLabel={(option) =>
                      option.prodName + " " + option.size
                    }
                    // getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.label ?? ""}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                        label="Product"
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />

          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FieldArray;
```

**Update**

this is the submit button in `step1.js`

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // action(data);
    console.log(data, "d");
    const newOrder = [];
    data.order.forEach(({ product, variation }) => {
      const newVariantion = [];
      variation.forEach(({ qty, color }) => {
        newVariantion.push({ qty: parseInt(qty), color });
      });
      newOrder.push({ product, variation: newVariantion });
    });

    actions.updateAction(data);
    console.log(newOrder, "new order");
    navigate("/step2", newOrder);
  };
```

**Update:**
How would I be able to push the product ID inside the `newOrder` where it matches the productID of the selected product?

[image]

Comment: You can use localstorage to save it.

Comment: @DharmikPatel but how would I be able to do it? Since, there could be instances where there could be multiple products that will be chosen?

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70163292/reactjs-get-id-instead-of-value-from-material-ui-autocomplete

Comment: and please don't use localstorage - unless you want to save data between sessions (aka refresh page)

Comment: @AlexanderB. yes, but I would also need to pass the `id` and the label or the product name as well. I tried that example before but that would only saved the id, however, in my case, I need the id and the product name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some development on answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70163292/reactjs-get-id-instead-of-value-from-material-ui-autocomplete):

You can always add useState with a first product (save entire product, not just an id) and then manage everything through onChange:

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

/*...something here...*/
const FieldArray = ({ control, register, setValue, getValues }) => {
  const [prod, setProd] = useState({0: product[0]});
  /*...something here...*/
  {fields.map((item, index) => {
    /*...something here...*/
    <Autocomplete
      onChange={(e, v)=>{console.log(v); setProd({...prod, [index]:v});}}
      value={prod[index] || {}}
      options={products}
      /*...other stuff here...*/
```

Have a look at what is available in `console.log(v)` inside `onChange`.

Also check out difference between `inputValue` and `value` [here](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#controlled-states).

**Update**

If you need multiple products to be saved - prod must be an object with key to represent "fields" item. For example, something like this `{0: prod1, 1: prod3, 2: prod11}`. Then for `value` use `prod[index]` and change setter appropriately. (I've edited code above for this case). There is multiple ways to do this - that's just one from top of my head.

**Update 2:**

I don't know what you want in onSubmit exactly, so here is an idea and you change it to what you want.

In *Step1.onSubmit* you can do something like that:

```js
// forEach 2nd argument is an index (counter) 
data.order.forEach(({ product, variation }, indx) => {
  // some code
  newOrder.push({ product, variation: newVariantion, prod: prod[indx] });
  // more code
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that I can't add multiple products. It won't allow me to choose different products - here's the codesandbox sample where it won't allow me to add different products  - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-from-reddit-with-data-forked-ww82c9?file=/src/fieldArray.js

Comment: But is there some way where I could add the `id` of the product together with the selected product name upon submitting it? I have updated the post as well where I added the submission of these data. Also in this way, the selected product does not show in the `console.log(newOrder)` - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-from-reddit-with-data-forked-ww82c9?file=/src/fieldArray.js

Comment: So the question is how you pass state/data from child component to a parent? Idea: 1) create a function handleProdChange(prod) in step1 that will update a step1's prod state, 2) pass this function to FieldArray 3) call this function with changed value of prod in onChange callback function, 4) in step1's onSubmit - read prod variable with your products.

Comment: Here is sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-from-reddit-with-data-forked-jurxr8  Look for ```Step1.prod = ``` in console

Comment: I'm really sorry for all the questions. But how would I be able to push the product ID inside the newOrder where it matches the productID of the selected product? I've updated the post as well - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-getting-the-id-of-each-of-the-product-k8ck9g?file=/src/fieldArray.js

Comment: You have ```prod``` that contains all info about new products inside onSubmit. I'm not sure what is data there and where it is coming from - so in ```Update 2``` I just plug ```prod``` info inside newOrder based on index... But it's your responsibility to make sure that it works as you need it to.

Comment: ohh alright. Thank you for the help